# Print the smallest string that can be repeated to get the original string

Tags: c++, string

**Sample Input** 
`abababab`
**Sample Output** 
`ab`

```
1 <= length of string <= 5000
```

What I am doing is recording the number of occurrences of each character. Then I find the smallest non-zero occurrence and and divide all the others by this number. Then I add everything and this gives me the length up to which I need to print the original string to give me the answer.
In the sample input, a=4, b=4. So the smallest occurrence is 4 and after division I get a=1, b=1 and addition gives me 2. I will print first 2 from original string to get `ab`. 
I even tried more complex examples and this algorithm seems to work flawlessly but I am still getting a few test cases wrong.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */   
    char str[5005];
    int letters[26] = {0}, min = 10000, len=0;
    cin>>str;
    int lent = strlen(str);
    if(lent==1)
    {
        cout<<str;
        return 0;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<lent; i++)
        letters[(int)str[i]-97]++;
    for(int i=0; i<26; i++)
    {
        if(letters[i]>0)
        {
            if(letters[i]<min)min=letters[i];
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<26; i++)
    {
        len+= letters[i]/min;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
        cout<<str[i];
    return 0;
}
```

**Please suggest the correct approach**

Comment: What _errors_ are you having?

Comment: Consider the output for `aabb`.

Comment: Have you tried input `aaabbaaabb`?

Comment: What would a correct answer be for `"abbab"`, and *why*?  And would your code actually deliver that correct answer? Competitive programming exercise questions are generally poor question candidates for SO, and summarizing said-same to the point where expectations are left to the imagination only confirms that.

Comment: Hint: every number up to 5000 has less than 50 divisors, half of them < 71

Comment: _"I am still getting a few test cases wrong."_ This is not an acceptable problem statement.

Comment: Wow, I did not think of such test cases. Please can someone help me with the correct approach ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As pointed out by the sample inputs given by Ryan and  Hagen von Eitzen in the comments and using the hint given by WhozCraig I was finally able to get the right approach.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */   
    string str;
    int letters[26] = {0}, min = 10000, len=0;
    cin>>str;
    int lent = str.size();
    len = lent;
    for(int i=1; i<=lent; i++)
    {
        string temp = "";
        string ans = "";
        if(lent%i == 0)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
                ans+=str[j];
            for(int j=0; j<(lent/i); j++)
                temp+=ans;
            if(str==temp)
            {
                cout<<ans;
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```